# Markdown syntax: problems with superscript

Tags: r, markdown, superscript

This is my first time using R so this is about as basic of a question as they come.

I am making a presentation using markdown (ioslides). I want to do something very simple which is to put something in superscript. According to the manual, the syntax is the following:

Lower bound = α^Full – K^ - α^Full^

The first time I tried running this, I got a pop-up screen with some options. Too quickly, I pressed enter and inadvertently chose something. Now the syntax won't run and I can't figure out what I did to undo it.

Can someone help? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Markdown [allows HTML to be used](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) if necessary, so you should be able to use the HTML [sup](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/sup.html) tag.